# JSON Serialization used by com.azure:azure-cosmos in JAVA

Tags: java, azure, serialization, azure-cosmosdb

I have a POJO of type `Item` that I want to store in CosmosDB using `com.azure:azure-cosmos` Java package.

Let's say that `Item` class is defined as follows:

```
@Getter
public class Item{
    private final Month month;


    public Item(Month month) {
        this.month = month
    }
}
```

with `Month` being `enum`.

```
public enum Month {

  January {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "January";
    }
  },
  February{
    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "Feb";
    }
  }
}
```

To store my item in CosmosDB I do the following:

```
Item item = new Item();
myContainer.createItem(item, new PartitionKey(...), ...);
```

Because I consider `Item` to be part of my contract I would like to write a simple unit test that verifies it serializes and deserializes properly, e.g. someone does not accidentally change name of property, enum converts well etc.

How can I do that? What mechanism is used by Azure Cosmos library under the hood? I know that in .NET, developer can specify [serializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.cosmos.cosmosclientoptions.serializer?view=azure-dotnet-preview) but I couldn't find the equivalent in JAVA.

Comment: it uses `com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind` you can override the object factory for serialization/deserialization for instance (here for example explained how to override it for reading/writing https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/17047)